# Passing json object to jquery ui function for dynamically adding <option> tag from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

I am really new to jquery UI and what i need to do is to pass a json object i am getting from facebook's graph api

```
$pageIds=$facebook->api('/me/accounts');
```

Now i need to pass $pageid to the jqueryUI function to dynamically add to the  tag by

```
$('#list').append($("<option></option>").
              attr("value",key).
              text(value);
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a .php file, do:

```
foreach ( $pageIds as $pageid ) {
    ?>
    $('#list').append($("<option></option>").
          attr("value", <?php echo $pageid; ?> ).
          text(value);
    <?php
}
```

This outputs the jquery syntax for appending the options.